# Command fails to run in RMarkdown despite working in regular R Script

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have this command and it works fine when I run it from an R script

```
df <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(Sys.glob("myfolder/part-*.parquet"), arrow::read_parquet)) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(mycol = as.character(mycol))
```

But, when I run the same command from an RMarkdown paragraph, I get this error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `mycol`.
x object 'mycol' not found
ℹ Input `mycol` is `as.character(mycol)`.
```

And then when I run the command without the last line, then I get an empty data frame.

I'm on the most up to date r studio with the most up to date R on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default search path for a Markdown document is the folder where the document is located.
This might be different from the working directory used by the RStudio session.
Verify that the .Rmd file is located in the `getwd()` folder.

To avoid path problems, a very effective solution under RStudio is :

1. to work with [Projects](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects) instead of standalone files
2. to use the [`here`](https://github.com/r-lib/here) package which allows you to reference files according to the project root, see also [Ode to the here package](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here)